# AngularJS - Controller cannot read ng-model object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

**I want to make a controller that can be reused by other views.
(This controller will serve as a template)**

The problem is that I can't make a simple validation because it can't read the properties that is set in `ng-model` unless I made changes on a field, then that property will be added to that object.

I don't want to put `ng-init="object.fieldName = null"` to every field in my view because I believe that it's not a good practice. I tried using `$watch` but the **object is still equals to {}**

Here's my Controller:

```
angular.module('practiceApp')
.controller("CreateModalController", function($scope, items, defaultService) {

    function initialize() {
        $scope.object = {}; // <---- this should contain the ng-model object properties
        $scope.defaultService = defaultService;
        $scope.modalTitle = items.modalTitle;

        $scope.$watch('object', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        }, true);
    }

    initialize();

});
```

Here's my view:

```
<form name = "objectForm"
      role = "form">
      <input type="text" 
             ng-model="object.firstName" 
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="First Name" 
             ng-class="{'error-textfield': defaultService.isNotValid(object.firstName)}"
             required>

      <input type="text" 
             ng-model="object.lastName" 
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="Last Name" 
             ng-class="{'error-textfield': defaultService.isNotValid(object.lastName)}"
             required>
</form>
```

current output => `object: {}`

desired output    => `object: {firstname: undefined, lastName: undefined}`

Comment: I don't see you calling the initialise function in the view.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling the initialize function in the view" ? I updated the code above to make it complete but I only call the initialize function in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

The output will initially be `object: {}` because you haven't initially declared `$scope.object` to have any properties on it. It will only have the `firstName` or`lastName` property visible when you enter text into the `<input>` to trigger `ng-model` into updating `$scope.object`.

If you want to have it initially show has the desired output you've provided, declare your object initially in the controller to have undefined properties:

```
$scope.object = {
  firstName: undefined,
  lastName: undefined
};
```

On a side note, you shouldn't need to self-initialize via your `initialize()` function in your controller if you've already declared the controller in your routing.

Also, if you're using AngularJS 1.5+ components, you can use `$onInit()`.

Comment: hmm.. the problem with that is the object variable will be used by other create features as well.. so the properties shouldn't be static.

Comment: For the `initialize() function`, i just want to keep my code organize

Comment: @KennethC, if the goal here is validation of these variables, why not validate on the template with AngularJS form-validation? That way your controller can be completely ignorant of the properties on `$scope.object`.

Answer (score 0):

see working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
  
  
  var app = angular.module('practiceApp', []);
  app.controller("CreateModalController", function($scope) {

    function initialize() {
        $scope.object = {
          firstName: null,
          lastName: null
        }; // <---- this should contain the ng-model object properties
        //$scope.defaultService = defaultService;
        //$scope.modalTitle = items.modalTitle;

        $scope.$watch('object', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        }, true);
    }

    initialize();

});
  
  
</script>
<div ng-app="practiceApp" ng-controller="CreateModalController">
<form name="objectForm"
      role="form">
      <input type="text" 
             ng-model="object.firstName" 
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="First Name" 
             ng-class="{'error-textfield': defaultService.isNotValid(object.firstName)}"
             required>

      <input type="text" 
             ng-model="object.lastName" 
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="Last Name" 
             ng-class="{'error-textfield': defaultService.isNotValid(object.lastName)}"
             required>
  
</form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Even if you don't want to initialize values you will see values of firstName and lastName after you start typing.
While user don't enter anything into input fields there was no values in 'object' so there is nothing to show.

Any questions?

Comment: The `object` variable shouldn't be static, because I will be using that as a template.

Comment: What is your actual task? and why you want to see object with all fields in console ?

Comment: It's just an example, I want to validate the properties first then I'm planning to store it via ajax.

Comment: I'm gonna loop through all the properties of the object then check if there's a `null`, `undefined`, or empty string.

Comment: I see. Why don't you use 'required' or 'ng-required'? or use form.$valid ?

Comment: Also, I can recommend to look on telerik controls -> there is a good one named kendo-window. They have angular-integrated version. It works OK for me.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll check it first if it'll work. i'm busy right now so I can't test it. Maybe I incorrectly analyzed the problem.

Comment: _ no problem _.